# Finding all users in roles

Tags: liferay

I would like to find out all of the user which are associated in some roles. I have seen the UserLocalService that provides the method to find the users in a particular role. But I want a method to which I can pass an array of roleIds and it shall return me the list of users in those roles.
One way is to write custom SQL, but I would like to get it done by using the API only.
Is that possible with Liferay API??

Comment: There is no API available for it AFAIK. Also `UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers` will give you only Regular Role users not Site/Organization role users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the API multiple times? Create a new service that does this for you so that you only have a single call to (your) API?

I know, this is probably not the answer that you expected. Note that roles in Liferay can be scoped globally (to the whole portal, called 'regular') or to an individual site or organization. Thus just giving a roleId would limit you to the global roles (as the others would require the site's or organization's groupId).

Stepping back and looking at what you want to achieve, my first guess is that you have some semantics in being associated with a specific role - kind of like... a usergroup? A role is designed to give permissions to users, while a usergroup is designed to group users. `UserLocalService` also has `getUserGroupUsers` - this also only takes a single usergroup id, but at least it's a single (global) scope by definition and not ambiguous like roles.